# How to animate a radar char of d3 in my next.js component without creating overlapping graphics?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am currently facing an issue with my RadarChart component in React. The chart itself generates correctly, but when I click on my page and set a new state with updated values, the RadarChart draws a new graphic on top of the previous one. Instead, I want to animate the existing chart smoothly with the new values, without creating overlapping graphics.

I have tried passing the new state values directly to the RadarChart component, but it seems to create a new chart every time without animating the existing one. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
/** @format */

import RadarChart from '@/components/chart/RadarChart';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Graph() {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([
    { name: 'Build', value: 5 },
    { name: 'Technical Due Diligence', value: 4 },
    { name: 'Tech Parner Service', value: 3 },
    { name: 'Advisory', value: 2 },
    { name: 'Product Development', value: 4 },
    { name: 'Resource', value: 3 },
  ]);

  const handleLinkClick = newData => {
    setChartData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a
        href='#'
        onClick={() =>
          handleLinkClick([
            { name: 'Build', value: 1 },
            { name: 'Technical Due Diligence', value: 2 },
            { name: 'Tech Parner Service', value: 3 },
            { name: 'Advisory', value: 4 },
            { name: 'Product Development', value: 6 },
            { name: 'Resource', value: 5 },
          ])
        }
      >
        Growth
      </a>{' '}
      <a
        href='#'
        onClick={() =>
          handleLinkClick([
            { name: 'Build', value: 3 },
            { name: 'Technical Due Diligence', value: 4 },
            { name: 'Tech Parner Service', value: 5 },
            { name: 'Advisory', value: 7 },
            { name: 'Product Development', value: 5 },
            { name: 'Resource', value: 3 },
          ])
        }
      >
        Mature
      </a>
      <RadarChart data={chartData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the RadarChart component, I'm using a library (not specified) to render the chart based on the data prop. However, instead of animating the existing chart with the updated values, it creates a new chart on top of the previous one.

I have looked into the documentation of the library I'm using and searched for similar issues, but I couldn't find a solution specific to animating the RadarChart component without overlapping graphics. I believe I might be missing a crucial step or misunderstanding how to properly update the chart with new data while preserving the existing chart.

How can I animate the existing RadarChart smoothly with the updated values, without generating overlapping graphics each time the state is updated? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
/** @format */

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const RadarChart = ({ data }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Tamaño del gráfico
    const width = 500;
    const height = 500;
    const maxTextWidth = 150;

    // Datos para el gráfico de radar
    const chartData = data,
    ];

    const wrap = (text, width) => {
      text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
          x = text.attr('x'),
          y = text.attr('y'),
          dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
          tspan = text
            .text(null)
            .append('tspan')
            .attr('x', x)
            .attr('y', y)
            .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
        while ((word = words.pop())) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(' '));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text
              .append('tspan')
              .attr('x', x)
              .attr('y', y)
              .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
              .text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    };

    // Radio del gráfico
    const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    // Escalas y configuraciones del gráfico
    const angleScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
      .domain(chartData.map(d => d.name));

    const radiusScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, 10]);

    // Crear un SVG en el contenedor
    const svg = d3.select(ref.current).attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height]);

    // Crear un grupo para el gráfico de radar
    const radarGroup = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`);

    // Gradiente
    const gradient = svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('radialGradient')
      .attr('id', 'gradient') // Id para referenciar después
      .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse') // Esto determina cómo se distribuye el gradiente
      .attr('cx', 0)
      .attr('cy', 0) // Centro del gradiente
      .attr('r', radius) // Radio del gradiente
      .selectAll('stop')
      .data([
        { offset: '0%', color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' },
        {
          offset: '70%',
          color: 'transparent',
        }, // Color en el centro del gradiente
        { offset: '100%', color: 'transparent' }, // Color en el borde del gradiente
      ])
      .enter()
      .append('stop')
      .attr('offset', d => d.offset)
      .attr('stop-color', d => d.color);

    // Dibujar líneas radiales
    const radialLines = radarGroup
      .selectAll('.radial-lines')
      .data(chartData)
      .join('line')
      .attr('class', 'radial-lines')
      .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr(
        'x2',
        d => radiusScale(10) * Math.cos(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr(
        'y2',
        d => radiusScale(10) * Math.sin(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr('stroke', 'url(#gradient)');

    // Agregar etiquetas al final de las líneas radiales
    radarGroup
      .selectAll('.radial-labels')
      .data(chartData)
      .join('text')
      .attr('class', 'radial-labels')
      .attr(
        'x',
        d => (radiusScale(9) + 0) * Math.cos(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr(
        'y',
        d => (radiusScale(9) + 0) * Math.sin(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .text(d => d.name)
      .call(wrap, maxTextWidth) // Aquí utilizamos la función wrap
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('dominant-baseline', 'middle');

    // Dibujar el polígono para los valores de datos
    const area = d3
      .lineRadial()
      .angle(d => angleScale(d.name))
      .radius(d => radiusScale(d.value));

    // Dibujar el polígono para los valores de datos
    const lineGenerator = d3
      .line()
      .x(d => radiusScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2))
      .y(d => radiusScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleScale(d.name) - Math.PI / 2))
      .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed);

    radarGroup
      .append('path')
      .datum(chartData)
      .attr('d', lineGenerator)
      .attr('fill', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.05)') // Área transparente
      .attr('stroke', 'blue') // Borde azul
      .attr('stroke-width', 4)
      .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round') // Bordes redondeados
      .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round'); // Bordes redondeados
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <svg
      ref={ref}
      style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw', display: 'block' }}
    />
  );
};

export default RadarChart;
```